# How to show html in react native webView?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using a webView for rendering a piece of html but instead of rendering it shows the code. What is the problem?

My code is...

```
<WebView
    source = {scoLocal['sco']}
    javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    style={[styles.textArea, {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      maxHeight: '100%',
      maxWidth: '100%'
  }]}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should show the scoLocal, probably that is the reason you are getting an error. The general usage is shown below.

```
    <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: '<p>This is an HTML p tag</p>' }}
    />
```

or

```
    const htmlSource = '<p>This is an HTML p tag</p>'
    <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: htmlSource }}
    />
```

Have a nice one!

Comment: So I can´t import or call the html with path file? something like 
var scoLocal = {
  'sco': require('../assets/sco/story.html')
}

Comment: If you want to use a local file you should do source={{ uri: scoLocal['sco'] }}.

Comment: Can you mark it as an answer if it was useful?